# ModuleNotFoundError when installing Cython module through pip on Windows, but not on Linux

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I'm trying to build a python module in the folder `mymodule` containing some cython code. However, on Windows, installing it via pip, it cannot find Cython even though it is installed. On Linux, no such problem occurs.

As a minimal example, let's say I have a cython file `calculations.pyx` and a `setup.py`.

```
mymodule
|
|-- calculations.pyx
+-- setup.py
```

The `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='mymodule',
    version='0.1',
    
    install_requires=['Cython'],
    ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(
        'calculations',
        sources=['calculations.pyx'],
    )),
)
```

When I'm installing this module (`pip install -e mymodule`) on Linux, the module installs correctly and cython builds the binaries. When I'm trying to install the module on Windows, i get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'` error. However, if I just build the extension myself using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, it works correctly.

I have verified that Cython is already installed. Even if it wasn't installed, it should be installed after running the `pip install -e mymodule` command, since it is listed in the `install_requires` list. I have verified this on Linux, and there Cython is correctly installed as a depenency if it wasn't present before running the `setup.py`.

What could be the issue here?
Also, I have only one Python version installed, not multiple.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue: I found a solution that made it work, even though I don't understand why. By putting a `pyproject.toml` file in the root directory `mymodule`, which tells pip the packages required to even run `setup.py`. Source: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html

The toml file:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "Cython"]
```

Now it works and compiles. However, I still do not understand why it worked on Linux and also why it didn't work on Windows even though I had cython alredy installed.